# Jekyll Liquid Syntax, how to dereference a property

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am grouping the posts on my site using this liquid tag.

```
{% assign postsForYear = site.posts | group_by_exp:"post", "post.date | date: '%Y'" | where: "name", "2020" %}
```

When I echo the `postForYear` out to screen, I see this:

```
{"name"=>"2020", "items"=>[#, #, #, #, #, #], "size"=>6} 0
```

Which makes sense, as I have six posts for that year.  However, I am trying to dereference that object and get the `.size` property, which I can see in the output...I can't figure out the syntax!

### How to get the .Size property?

None of these work.

```
{{ postsForYear.size }}
{{ postsForYear.items | size }}
```

After that, I would love to learn how to foreach my way through the posts...this also seems simple but doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I figured it out.  Strangely, the `postsForYear` array was actually treated like an array itself, so I had to index into the first position to get to the properties.

```
{% assign postsForYear = site.posts | 
    group_by_exp:"post", "post.date | date: '%Y'" | where: "name", "2020" %} 

###doesn't work
{{ postsForYear.items | size }}

### does work
{{ postsForYear[0].items | size }}

### example
Posts for year {{ postsForYear[0].name }}, total posts {{ postsForYear[0].size }} 

>Posts for year 2020, total posts 6
```

And to answer my other question, how to foreach your way through:

```
{% for post in postsForYear[0].items %}
   <h1>{{post.title}}</h1><br>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Comment: For the record, the array is created by the `group_by`, as shown in the documentation: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#group-by `{{ site.members | group_by_exp: "item",
"item.graduation_year | truncate: 3, ''" }}`  would gives something like `[{"name"=>"201", "items"=>[...]},
{"name"=>"200", "items"=>[...]}]`

Comment: Ah, make's sense.  Thank you!

Comment: This said I don't really see why you do group. You could just do: `where: "post", "post.date | date: '%Y' == 2020"` (or `== '2020'`, possibly because I'd expect date to return a string)